# Can you record multiple rides on a Garmin 500 and download more than one on Strava?

Tags: garmin, strava

Can you record multiple rides on a Garmin 500 and then download them sequentially onto Strava?

Valerie Jones

Answer (score 5):

> Can you record multiple rides on Garmin 500

Yes you can record as many rides as there is room on the internal memory. Once you have completed a ride hit stop, then hold the lap/reset button for 3 seconds to get the unit to save the ride and reset the screen.  This will save the ride as a .fit file on the unit (Figure 1).

The Garmin 500 is an older unit with less memory, but right now I have 124 rides on my Garmin 500 dating back to Nov 2018 and there is still plenty of room left.

> then download them sequencially onto strava

You will need to connect the Garmin unit to a compatible computer using the supplied USB cable, it will typically mount as an external drive (Figure 1). From there you can manually upload the .fit files to Strava using their [file upload feature](https://www.strava.com/upload/select).

Alternatively you can install [Garmin Express](https://www.garmin.com/en-US/software/express) on your computer, which will automatically upload the .fit files to [Garmin Connect](https://connect.garmin.com/) when you connect the your Garmin 500 to your computer.  [Strava](https://www.strava.com/upload/device) can then be set up to connect and download activities from [Garmin Connect](https://connect.garmin.com/).

Personally, I just do it old school (file upload).

[image: Figure 1]
Figure 1. Location of Garmin 500 activity files.

Answer (score 1):

I googled your exact question as written and the top match is

https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918057-Garmin-and-Strava

which says

> After your first upload, Garmin will also sync your past 90 days of activity to Strava.

Remember garmin devices aren't cell phones, the current models depend on either a computer connection (via USB) or a cellphone (via bluetooth) to push your data to Garmin Connect.

From there the Strava integration is a "third party app" [1] and has to be authorised to connect with Garmin Connect.  Once this is done, 90 days of your Garmin Connect records will be pushed to Strava.

Comment: [1] A bit of turn-about for Strava to be the third party app !  Wonder how they like being relegated like that :)

Comment: One (of several) reasons I will probably choose another brand of bike computer next time I need one.  People have bought garmin for years because it was basically alone as a half decent product in the market.  Now thankfully we are starting to see a good few alternatives.

Comment: @AndyP I'm very happy with my Wahoo. Uploads automatically to Strava via either my cell phone or my home WiFi as soon as I finish the ride. (Or, if you don't want it to do that, you can tell it not to.)

Comment: @AndyP I can’t complain too much about my Garmin Edge 500, 10 years of daily use and it still works fine. It even received a feature update last year (additional power summaries). Pretty good service life IMHO and even 10 years in I am not left wanting features, although I am not a keen Strava uploader either.